# Manually select tabstrip in Kendo ui mobile

Tags: kendo-ui

I am using Kendo ui mobile. I am opening a modal view when a tabstrip item is selected as shown in the screenshot (Show Modal.png).

[image]

In the select method of kendo ui mobile tabstrip I am preventing  the default event propagation i.e, to show the modal view by using e.preventDefault(),  to show a confirmation dialog box as shown in the screenshot(Prevent Default Action.png).

[image]

Code:-

(Html part)

```
<div id='modal_tabs' data-role="tabstrip" data-select='tabChange'>
    <a href="#index" data-icon="custom">Home</a>
</div>
```

(JS part)

```
function tabChange(e) {
    if (someCondition) {
        e.preventDefault();
        showConfirmation(showPopUpMsg, 'Unsaved changes', doTabActiveOnOK); // show confirmation dialog box
    }
    doTabActiveOnOK = function (button) {   // callback function
        if (button == true) { //  if ok button is pressed
            $("#modal_tabs").data("kendoMobileTabStrip").select(1);  // not supported
        }
    }
}
```

If  'ok'  button is pressed on the confirmation dialog I want to perform the default action again(to show the modal) or select the tabstrip manually.  How to perform this task?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you still need this but you can use [switchTo](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/mobile/tabstrip#methods-switchTo) instead of select:

```
var tabStrip = $("#modal_tabs").data("kendoMobileTabStrip");
tabStrip.switchTo("#tabId");
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I don't need this now as I have changed the flow. Thanks again for helping...:)

Answer (score 1):

```
function ChangeTabStrip(DivID) {
    var tabStrip = app.view().footer.find(".km-tabstrip").data("kendoMobileTabStrip");
    tabStrip.switchTo("#" + DivID);
    app.navigate("#" + DivID, "slide");
}
```